# DelphiXE 10 Undeclared identifier: 'PAnsiChar'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Почему так? ведь это стандартный тип.

[image: DelphiXE Undeclared identifier: 'PAnsiChar']

Comment: Скорее всего у вас опечатка. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе** (не скриншотом). Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант: в качестве целевой платформы выбрана мобильная, а для них `PAnsiChar, AnsiString` не поддерживается.

[Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop)

> Eliminate Data Types that Are Not Supported by the Delphi Mobile Compilers
>   Code that uses any of the following unsupported types should
>   either be eliminated or rewritten to use an alternate type:
>
> WideString, AnsiString, ShortString, AnsiChar, **PAnsiChar**,
>   PWideChar, Openstring

Одна из альтернатив обхода: 
https://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2015/04/byte-strings-for-xe8s-mobile-compilers/

Comment: Да. Всё верно. Я писал для платформы андроид.